# PHP - Convert two sets of numbers (hr and min) into time

Tags: php, mysql, time, numbers, concatenation

In php is there a way to turn two integers (09 and 30) into into type time (9:30). I need this function so I can INSERT these number into a column in MySQL of type time.

Comment: The function is called [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). The manual has examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[setTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php)

```
$datetime = new DateTime(); 
$datetime->setTime(9, 30, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime::format ( string $format )
```

will do

```
$str = '09:' +'30';
$date = DateTime($str);
$date->format('H:i')
```

Answer (score 1):

> In php is there a way to turn two integers (09 and 30) into into type time (9:30). I need this function so I can INSERT these number into a column in MySQL of type time.

Yes, by formating them as string:

```
$hr  = 9;
$min = 30;

$time = sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hr, $min);

echo $time; # 09:30
```

Answer (score 0):

As hakre said, use sprintf.

```
$hours = 9;
$minutes = 30;

$time = sprintf("%02d:%02d:00", $hours, $minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a1 = array("09","30");
$date implode(":",$a1);
```